# Extra digits with printf Hex

Tags: c++

Why do I get extra digits after the string of Hex digits when using printf?

```
cout << printf("%06X ", 0xABCDEF);
```

produces: ABCDEF 7

So where does the 7 come from and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 12):

You need to use either cout or printf, not both.

```
printf("%06X ", 0xABCDEF);
```

Or

```
cout << hex << 0xABCDEF;
```

When you do both, the cout prints the result of the printf function, which is the number of characters printed (six characters and a space).

Answer (score 8):

You're passing the result of the printf operation to cout.

Generally speaking, you use either printf or cout.

```
printf("%06X",0xABCDEF); //will do what you want in a C-like way
```

and

```
std::cout << std::hex << 0xABCDEF; //is the C++ iostream way
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
cout << hex << 0xABCDEF;
```

The '7' is the return value of the printf() function. It is printed by cout, where the hex string is printed by the printf().

Comment: You should probably qualify those with namespace `std`.

Answer (score 3):

printf doesn't work together with cout. printf formats your value and prints it, it doesn't return the formatted value.

The 7 comes from the fact that printf returned that value, which is the total number of characters written. This 7 is then sent to cout, which prints it.

If you want to print formatted text using cout, the simplest way is to use [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/format/index.html), but the iostreams library also provides functionality for this via [manipulators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/).